# assigning / validation of signature using RSA (PKCS 7)

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi

Any suggestions for simple and fast library for assigning / validation of signature using RSA Cryptographic Messaging Operations (PKCS#7)?

Comment: signatures and encryption are different things. Which (or both) are you interested in?

Answer (score 3):

Crypto++ has been, in my opinion and experience, the best for encrypting and decrypting data for any platform.

http://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: Crypto++ doesn't support PKCS#7, and isn't trivial to do that with the documented features.

Answer (score 2):

Although not nearly as easy to use as Crypto++, openssl has support for PKCS#7 based standards. You can look at apps/cms.c for an examples of everything you'd need. Another option is RSA BSAFE-C, which is available in a free version for something called the RSA Share program. Looking at the [developers guide](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-4948), chapter 5 shows that PKCS#7 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I use [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) (relies on OpenSSL), which is relatively easy to use. But I think you need Qt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can not adopt the use of Qt. (client decision)